# generate order number sequentially

Tags: c#

I have a requirement that I need to generates an order number in (Sequentially) not random that should be shown to user before giving the order.

```
        private string GenerateOrderNumber()
    {
        string OrderNumber;

        //JI-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX
        Random rnd = new Random();
        long orderPart1 = rnd.Next(100000, 9999999);
        int orderPart2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);

        OrderNumber = "JI-" + orderPart1 + "-" + orderPart2;

        return OrderNumber;
    }
```

Comment: OK. Was there a question?

Comment: i want to generate number in squential JI-000000-0001 for next order JI-000000-002

Comment: That is not a question, that is a requirement. Please make it an actuall question.

Comment: You say "_not random_", but your code generates random numbers so which is it? If it is not suppose to be random then what is the max range? Can it be `JI-999999-9999` or only `JI-000000-9999`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
long orderPart1 = 100000;
int orderPart2 = 1000;

Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("JI-{0}-{1}", orderPart1, orderPart2));

orderPart2++;

Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("JI-{0}-{1}", orderPart1, orderPart2));

orderPart2 = 9999;

if(orderPart2 == 9999)
{
    orderPart1++;
    orderPart2 = 1000;
}

Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("JI-{0}-{1}", orderPart1, orderPart2));
```

Which outputs:

```
JI-100000-1000
JI-100000-1001
JI-100001-1000
```

So you can create a class:

```
void Main()
{
   OrderNumberGenerator orderNumberGenerator = new OrderNumberGenerator();

   Debug.WriteLine(orderNumberGenerator.Next());
   Debug.WriteLine(orderNumberGenerator.Next());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class OrderNumberGenerator
{
    long orderPart1 = 100000;
    int orderPart2 = 1000;

    public string Next()
    {
        if(orderPart2 == 9999)
        {
            orderPart1++;
            orderPart2 = 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            orderPart2++;
        }

        return string.Format("JI-{0}-{1}", orderPart1, orderPart2);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
JI-100000-1000
JI-100000-1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can generate all of the ids in sequence:

```
for (long n = 0; n <= 9999999999; n++)
{
    string digits = n.ToString("0000000000");
    string output = $"JI-{digits.Substring(0, 6)}-{digits.Substring(6, 4)}";
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: This would start from JI-0000-000000, I am guessing @mohamad damaj3 wants to start from: JI-1000-100000... I say this because of rnd.Next values. In one of his comments, he then wrote JI-000000-0001, so who knows.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia - It wouldn't be overly hard to change `n = 0` to `n = 1`.